# Ember.js belongsTo is not displayed in view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to display a model, with a hasMany relation and each of those relations has a belongsTo relation.

For some reason, Ember doesnt want to display the belongsTo.

Here are my models:

```
App.City = DS.Model.extend({
    city: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Child = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.belongsTo('city', {async: true})
});

App.Activity = DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany('child',{async:true}),
    name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

My template looks like this:

```
Activity name: {{name}}<br />
{{#each child in children}}
    Child name: {{child.name}}<br />
    Child city name: {{child.city.name}}
{{/each}}
```

**{{child.city.name}}** is empty.

I've created a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/N2xdx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your City fixtures you have:

```
App.City.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Aarhus'
    }
];
```

But your `App.City` doesn't have a `name: DS.attr('string')` mapping. Update your model to the following, and all will work:

```
App.City = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    city: DS.attr('string')
});
```

This is a fiddle with this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/vDaxt/